# Using cookies to remember if an article has been read or not - identifiers to note

Tags: javascript, css, cookies

I'm looking to set some sort of 'you've read this article' function on a site I'm building.

A small circle will be displayed beside the heading of each article that has/has not been read - unsure what works best. The former probably.

I'm wondering if anyone has worked on this sort of thing before/has it a name. I'm guessing some sort of cookie would be useful. However, I'm unsure whether it should just exist for that session and hence some simple CSS/JS would be suffice.

Any thoughts on the subject and any examples?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 1):

I would create a youHaveRead table which contains the userid and the articleid.

Do not use cookies because a user has control over it.

Also if you work with multiple devices you can't share the cookie.

For example you want those notifications everywhere like your mobile phone, computer, tablet, e-reader etc...

And this way you can view statistics about it to. ;)

But thats just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think, honestly, this is just an aesthetic value to keep users aware as they are reading the news articles on the site. A nice little feature but nothing that's over complicated. We have analytics on the site, so those help.

Comment: If you only want a fast small feature I think you only need `a:visited` to give a visited link another style.